# Unable to access value of livedata from a method in ViewModel

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

So I recently starting learning the MVVM architecture techniques and I have been having lots of problems with implementing the observers and the ViewModel. I have had very unexpected behavior inside my Fragment class with the observers. The arguments of the onChanged method keep changing their value from within the method (It's crazy).

The updatePeriodList() method in the VM keeps getting a NULL pointer exception even though I am fetching the data from the Repository.

```
    public class CalendarViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private CentralRepository mRepo;
    private LiveData<List<PeriodEntity>> pastPeriods;

    public CalendarViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepo = new CentralRepository(application);
        pastPeriods = mRepo.getAllPeriods();
    }

    public LiveData<List<PeriodEntity>> getPastPeriods() {
        return pastPeriods;
    }


    public void updatePeriodList(){
                List<PeriodEntity> pastList = new ArrayList<>();
                pastList = mRepo.getAllPeriods().getValue();
                List<PeriodEntity> fullList = new ArrayList<>();
                fullList = PredictionUtils.predictPeriods(pastList);
        if (fullList != null && fullList.get(pastList.size()).getStartTimestamp() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            return;
        }
        if(fullList != null){
            mRepo.insertPeriod(fullList.get(pastList.size()));
        }
    }
```

```
    public class CentralRepository {
    private JournalDao journalDao;
    private MoonDao moonDao;
    private PeriodDao periodDao;

    private LiveData<List<JournalEntity>> allJournals;
    private LiveData<List<MoonEntity>> allMoons;
    private LiveData<List<PeriodEntity>> allPeriods;

    public CentralRepository(Application application) {
        CentralDatabase db = CentralDatabase.getInstance(application);
        Log.e("MY LOG", "CENTRAL REPO CALLED");
        journalDao = db.journalDao();
        moonDao = db.moonDao();
        periodDao = db.periodDao();

        allJournals = journalDao.getAllJournals();
        allMoons = moonDao.getAllMoons();
        allPeriods = periodDao.getAllPeriods();
    }


    public void insertJournal(final JournalEntity journalEntity){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                journalDao.insert(journalEntity);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void insertMoon(final MoonEntity moonEntity) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                moonDao.insert(moonEntity);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void insertPeriod(final PeriodEntity periodEntity){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                periodDao.insert(periodEntity);
            }
        }).start();
    }


    public LiveData<List<JournalEntity>> getAllJournals() {
        return allJournals;
    }

    public LiveData<List<MoonEntity>> getAllMoons() {
        return allMoons;
    }

    public LiveData<List<PeriodEntity>> getAllPeriods() {
        return allPeriods;
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class CentralDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract JournalDao journalDao();
    public abstract MoonDao moonDao();
    public abstract PeriodDao periodDao();

    private static CentralDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static synchronized CentralDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    CentralDatabase.class, "central_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build();
        }
        Log.e("MY LOG", "CENTRAL DB CALLED");

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //perform all the insert operations here to initiate the tables with data

                    INSTANCE.moonDao().insert(new MoonEntity(100,200,300));

                    //Get this data from user when first time uses the app through insert methods
                    Calendar timestamp = Calendar.getInstance();
                    timestamp.set(2020,2,2);
                    timestamp.getTimeInMillis();
                    INSTANCE.periodDao().insert(new PeriodEntity(timestamp.getTimeInMillis(),timestamp.getTimeInMillis()+432000000L));
                    timestamp.set(2020,2,30);
                    timestamp.getTimeInMillis();
                    INSTANCE.periodDao().insert(new PeriodEntity(timestamp.getTimeInMillis(),timestamp.getTimeInMillis()+432000000L));
                    Log.e("MY LOG", "PERIOD INSERTED");
                }
            }).start();
        }
    };

}
```

observer in the fragment

```
calendarViewModel.getPastPeriods().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<PeriodEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(final List<PeriodEntity> pastperiods) {
                calendarViewModel.updatePeriodList();
                currentPeriod = pastperiods.get(pastperiods.size()-1);
                calendarDayList = DateUtils.calendarDaysGenerater(pastperiods);

                setPeriodOnCircle((int)(System.currentTimeMillis()-
                        (pastperiods.get(pastperiods.size()-1).getStartTimestamp())+86400000)/86400000);

                calendarView.addDecorator(new CurrentDayDecorator
                        (calendarView, DateUtils.calendarDaysGenerater
                                (PredictionUtils.predictPeriods(pastperiods)),R.color.colorPrimary));

            }
        });
```

I know it's a lot of code but please help me as I need to implement this app

Comment: add observer to that live value in fragment, then it will be working fine. and trigger the action when you get the observer callback.

Comment: observe pastPeriods in fragment

Comment: Already done that but still give a null pointer exception

Comment: can you share that piece of code ?

Comment: I have added the observer code

Comment: check the last part of the post

Comment: i see no issue in code. Are you sure that there is data in db and one thing more. Can you make the live data public and instead of calling the function, observe it directly ?

Comment: still null, only returns value from the observer